# Integrating instagram authentication in android

Tags: android, instagram-api

I am building an android application that uses the instagram APIs and i would like to know if there's a solution that avoids building an api (redirect uri) to handle redirect from instragram authentication endpoint for token retrieval for an android client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can make it with their [Client side (implicit) authentication](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/). Check the section at the end of the article.

> Once the user has authenticated and then authorized your application,
>   Instagram redirects them to your redirect_uri with the access_token in
>   the url fragment. It will look like this:
>
> http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
>
> Simply grab the
>   access_token off the URL fragment and you’re good to go. If the user
>   chooses not to authorize your application, you’ll receive the same
>   error response as in the explicit flow.

The key part is that you **have** to define a redirect uri, but in this case it has not to be valid. For example, if you use `www.google.com` as a redirect uri, after the authentication user will be redirected to

> http://www.google.com#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

At this point, you must **not** let the user go forward. Instead, catch the redirect and parse the URI string so you can have your access token.

If your navigation happens inside a WebView, this will likely happen in the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` callback (from WebViewClient):

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("http://www.google.com") { // redirect uri!
        String accessToken = ... // get token from url
        return true; // don’t load the page
    }
    return false;
}
```

It will be somewhat painful, for example for error handling, but hey, if they have a client side authentication, it should work for you too.